# Using Http status code in htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-codes

In an .htaccess file I can do something like `ErrorDocument 404 /error/404` to give a friendly error message. I'd like to do the same thing for other status codes, but I don't want to have to enter all of them in the htaccess file.

So is there a way to do a rewrite on the status code? Something like:

```
ErrorDocument [0-9]* /error/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't rewrite your error document like that.

You need to use a RewriteRule to rewrite your error Document.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3})/?$ /error/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I know I cannot do what I specified above, but is there a way to use the status code when it is not in the url? 
For instance, redirecting a 401 to error/401, without actually adding a new ErrorDocument entry to htaccess.

Comment: no, a single error document can not handle all http error.

Comment: @Coin_op

 if you are happy with the answer ,please accept it otherwise let me know how I can improve it.

Comment: But that is not a solution to the question. That simply rewrites a url not an error document code. Admittedly you do say its not possible, but you don't offer a decent alternative.